# Celery with continuous deployment

Tags: python, celery, continuous-deployment

I have a service that exposes an API which is then feeding tasks, it is implemented with Falcon (API) and Celery (task management).

Specifically, my workers take long time to load and their code looks something like this

```
class HeavyOp(celery.Task):
    def __init__(self):
        self._asset = get_heavy_asset()  # <-- takes long time

    @property
    def asset(self):
        return self._asset

@app.task(base=HeavyOp)
def my_task(data):

    return my_task.asset.do_something(data)
```

What actually goes on is that in the `__init__` function some object is being read from disk and held in memory for as long as the worker lives.

Sometimes, I want to update that object.

Is there a way to reload the worker, without downtime? As this is all behind an API, I don't wish to have those few minutes of loading the heavy object as downtime.

We can assume the host has more than 1 core, but the solution must be a single host solution.

Comment: Reloading the worker without downtime is not possible as far as I'm aware. Two ideas: 1. Run two workers and restart one after the other. 2. Create another task to perform my_task.asset = get_heavy_asset().

Comment: @BjoernStiel tried it, it didn't work though I'm not sure I did it right. How would I address form task B the asset from task A? it is already loaded in task A

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a custom base task class. What you want to achieve is a single instance asset class which gets loaded after the worker has initialised and you can reload from a task.

This approach works:

```
# worker.py
import os
import sys
import time

from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_ready


app = Celery(include=('tasks',))

class Asset:

    def __init__(self):
        self.time = time.time()



class AssetLoader:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        if '_value' not in self.__dict__:
            self.get_heavy_asset()

    def get_heavy_asset(self):
        self._value = Asset()

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value


@worker_ready.connect
def after_worker_ready(sender, **kwargs):
    AssetLoader()
```

Here, I made AssetLoader a Borg class, but you can choose any other pattern/strategy to share a single instance of Asset. For illustrative purposes, I just capture the timestamp when executing `get_heavy_asset`.

```
# tasks.py
from worker import app, AssetLoader


@app.task(bind=True)
def load(self):
    AssetLoader().get_heavy_asset()
    return AssetLoader().value.time

@app.task(bind=True)
def my_task(self):
    return AssetLoader().value.time
```

Bear in mind that Asset is shared per worker process but not across workers. If you run with `concurrency=1`, it doesn't make a difference, but for anything else it does. But from what I gather in your use case, it should be fine either way.

Comment: I'll go over the solution this weekend and try to implement it, I'll report if it works / fails - thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It could be due to the nature of the code - as I said in the main post - this is actually behind an API so it's not that my app is live in my command line. What happens in my setup, is that the asset gets loaded with each call

Comment: So you're saying that when you run `my_task` in the code above (with the 'mocked' `get_heavy_asset` call which just sets the timestamp) you see a new timestamp on every `my_task.s().delay()` call?

Comment: I'm not sure really what happened behind the scenes, on the first try as I changed the heavy object it changed automatically without any call in the workers. Later when I tried to reproduce I couldn't change it even when I called reloading function (which alters the Borg's shared state).

I'm assuming that each process gets its own borg and the shared states is per worker process, and I need all processes to use the same object

Comment: Yes. This is per worker process (see my note about concurrency=1). There is no way to share memory across processes.

Comment: So what is the meaning of the shared state in this case? I need a solution that will work on concurrency higher than 1 - There must be a way. I would use REDIS and read it from each task but I have to be able to read whatever object it is.

Comment: Shared state within the same process. If you need to run with concurrency > 1 you have to use a db, redis or whatever (which I thought from your initial explanation was to slow).

Comment: redis can't store any python object if i'm not mistaken, that is why it is not useful for me

Comment: You can pickle your Python object and store it in Redis (though I wouldn't recommend it). Or you write your own json serializer/deserializer and store the json blob in Redis.

Comment: I'm exploring this direction, but in the real use case, I get a loading function from a user which loads something I can't tell what it is. I only know that this function will load "SOMETHING" into memory, I can't tell what it is.